# How to parse multi-transfer transactions

Tags: transactions, transfer, logs, parser

Ok, I know how to parse the 'input' field of a transaction:

- we look for '0xa9059cbb' or '0x23b872dd' bytes at the beginning, if found:
- we split the rest of the 'input' field by 64-length strings which are:

  - `to addr`, `value` in case of `0xa9059cbb` 'Transfer' event
  - and `from addr`, `to addr`, `value` in case of `0x23b872dd` 'Transfer From' event

But, playing with blocks I found transactions that contain huge 'input' fields with many addresses, values, and kinda delimiters between groups of them. A couple of examples:
[one](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x70eb735df1e35d33083623b77a7210d2e7090698100ab35c20f9cd8b46b34a54), [two](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x47fa5dbbae7046832a1bdbf69503e8e896875014c10ca21d424ab3b376e59b4e#eventlog).

You can find the content of the 'input' field on `"Overview" tab -> More details -> Click to show more`. There are raw and parsed representations. You can see that it contains groups of sender/receiver/contract addresses delimited with `...0002c` strings. I can even conclude that the first address from the 'senders' block sends tokens (where to search for its value?) to the first address from the 'receivers' block via contract with the first address from the 'contracts' block. You can check it with Etherscan's Logs tab for this transaction.

So my questions are:

- is this bulk 'input' field form legitimate for ERC20 contracts and Ethereum transactions in general?
- is the field format stable or can vary from contract to contract?
- are there other forms of such multi-transfer transactions? any written rules about them? how to parse them?
- are there other contract Transfer functions that I would like to obtain from blocks besides the aforementioned `0xa9059cbb` or `0x23b872dd`? Any links to read about them?

PS: I see that these transfers are legitimate 'Transfer' events since the field 'Topics' on the 'Logs' tab for every transfer contains: `0xddf2...b3ef` which is the right topic to subscribe for 'Transfer' events. This is why I would like to be able to parse these grouped transfers too.
Another question here is: 'Is there a way to subscribe to events for certain block(s) from the past?'. If it were possible, I could parse transfers from certain blocks in the past easily without these hex-blobs parsing issues.